# How do I regain control of a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, administration

My website has a Facebook page that I don't have admin access for from my Facebook account.  It must have been created for me by somebody else.

How do I request access to this page from Facebook.  I can prove that the page is for me and my website.

Comment: [WebApps](//webapps.stackexchange.com/q/45485/35623) somewhat covers this. There are a handful of similar questions over there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, But users who created pages will only be able to add other admins to their pages via admin rules option from the fb page.

You can add yourselves to your page by requesting the page creator, page admin to add you via "admin rules" option from edit page option fro the page.

The one whom you mentioned as "somebody" should have permission to add users as admin..

Go now ask him to add your email address which gives you permission as admin.

Comment: In this case I just can't figure out who it would be.  I tried posting to the page itself and didn't get a response.   Is there any way to track down the admin?

Comment: Its is very easy to find out the admin of a FB page, go through this video and you may get solutions on finding who the admin is ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wev7EDZPec

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51987/how-to-find-the-admin-creator-of-a-fan-page-on-facebook says that you can only find the owner of the page if the owner has chosen to make themselves public.

Comment: Yes, its obviously true to the point. but in some instance using this tactics we can find out page admins..in FB

Comment: please see that video, it helps in finding out your page admin.

Comment: That video gives methods for when the admins are public or there is an email address for the page that is also used by the person who manages the page.  Unfortunately, neither are the case for me.

Comment: will come back soon with answers..

Comment: link of the page you want to find out admin ?

Comment: Here is my page: https://www.facebook.com/coinmillcurrency